# Is there any function in numpy to traverse an array in reverse order

Tags: python, numpy

I mean I have a 2d array. I can traverse it by row by row or column by column from the left side or the starting element. I want to do the same procedure starting from the top right and end at bottom right by row by row.
Also, want to traverse from top right and end at top left column by column.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: you can try this  `tmp = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] print([line for line in tmp[::-1]])`

Comment: "*starting from the top right and end at bottom right*". Do you rather mean ending at the bottom **left**? The question is unclear, you should provide a concrete example

Answer (score 0):

Try using np.flipud

```
import numpy as np
A = [1, 2,3,4,5]
np.flipud(A)
```

Output:

```
array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```